# Lenovo IdeaPad 110 AMD A9 WiFi Problem

Tags: wireless, lenovo

I used Lenovo IdeaPad 110 AMD A9 7th Generation

If I install Windows WiFi connection is no problem, but if I install Ubuntu the WiFi often disconnect/lost connect for every few minutes

$lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

```
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:a814]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
```